# Trying to take multiple excel spreadsheets, extract specific data, add them all to one dataframe and save it as a csv file

Tags: python, excel

Very new to this, so please go easy on me :)

Trying to take multiple excel spreadsheets, extract data specific from specific cells, add them all to one dataframe and save it as a csv file.

The csv output only contains the data from the last excel file. Please could you help?

```
 import pandas as pd
 import os
 from pathlib import Path

 ip = "//NETWORKLOCATION/In"
 op = "//NETWORKLOCATION/Out"

 file_exist = False
 dir_list = os.listdir(ip)
 print(dir_list)

 for xlfile in dir_list:
     if xlfile.endswith('.xlsx') or xlfile.endswith('.xls'):
         file_exist = True
         str_file = os.path.join(ip, xlfile)
         df1 = pd.read_excel(str_file)

         columns1 = {*VARIOUSDATA -* 
                     }

         #creates an empty dataframe for the data to all sequentially be added into
         df1a = pd.DataFrame([])

         #appends the array to the new dataframe df1a
         df1a = df1a.append(pd.DataFrame(columns1, columns = ['*VARIOUS COLUMNS*]))

         if not file_exist:
                 print('cannot find any valid excel file in the folder ' + ip)

                 print(str_file)

 df1a.to_csv('//NETWORKLOCATION/Out/Test.csv')
 print(df1a)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think You should put:

```
#creates an empty dataframe for the data to all sequentially be added into
df1a = pd.DataFrame([])
```

before `for xlfile in dir_list:` loop not inside the loop.
Otherwise `df1a` recreates empty on each file iteration.

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed it within 2 seconds. Have spent hours trying to figure out what I'd done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things. First, you'll never encounter:

```py
if not file_exist:
                 print('cannot find any valid excel file in the folder ' + ip)

                 print(str_file)
```

as is written, because it's a nested if statement and so file_exists is always set to true before it's reached.

2. You're creating df1a inside of your for loop. So you're always setting it back to empty.
3. Why import Path, and then use os.path and os.listdir?
   Why not just use Path(ip).glob('*.xls*')

This would look like:

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
from pathlib import Path

ip = "//NETWORKLOCATION/In"
op = "//NETWORKLOCATION/Out"

#creates an empty dataframe for the data to all sequentially be added into
df1a = pd.DataFrame([])

for xlfile in Path(ip).glob('*.xls*'):
    df1 = pd.read_excel(xlfile)

    columns1 = {"VARIOUSDATA"}

    #appends the array to the new dataframe df1a
    df1a = df1a.append(pd.DataFrame(columns1, columns = ['VARIOUS_COLUMNS']))

if df1a.empty:
    print('cannot find any valid excel file in the folder ' + ip)
    print(str_file)
else:
    df1a.to_csv(op+'/Test.csv')
    print(df1a)
```

Comment: Thanks. re 1 - agreed. Copied this code from elsewhere and didn't want to change it until I'd got it all to work. re 2 - this obviously fixed my issue, thanks. re 3 thanks for the advice - I'm a newbie and will review to help me to improve this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The csv output only contains the data from the last excel file.

You create the `df1a` `DataFrame` inside the `for loop`. Each time you read a new `xlfile` you create a new empty `DataFrame`.

You have to put `df1a = pd.DataFrame([])` on the 9th line of your script before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

import glob
glob.glob("C:\\your_path\\*.xlsx")

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("C:\\your_path\\*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)

type(all_data)
```

Check out this link.

https://pbpython.com/excel-file-combine.html